# watchPosition moves without mobile moving. JavaScript Google Maps

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps-api-3, geolocation, intel-xdk

I am currently using Google Maps API in Intel XDK, which gets the users position and displays markers, I also have it so if the user moves a marker it will get placed on the location they have moved to. in addition to this I have used polylines to draw a line between the two markers which also works as expected. The issue I am having is with the geolocation.watchPosition. When I deploy the application to my phone and run it the markers go down in a diagonal fashion (down and right every time) usually into the next street or 2 streets next to me in a perfectly straight line, however I haven't moved the location of my mobile device. if I get position of the user when using Navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition() it works fine and is also very accurate. At the moment the maps it is the only thing I have in the app, as I am simply trying to get it to update the players position accurately. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**Maps.js**

```
var map;
var pos;
var path = [];
var watchID;
var watchCallback;


function initialize() {

var mapOptions = {
   // center: new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng),
    zoom: 16,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
    mapTypeControl: true
};

var options = 
{
    enableHighAccuracy: true,
    timeout: Infinity,
    maximumAge: 0,
    frequency:2000
};

map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"),
                      mapOptions);

var onSuccess = function(position) 
{
    console.log(path.length);
    var lat =   position.coords.latitude;
    var lng =   position.coords.longitude;
    //var speed = position.coords.speed;        
    var pos = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
    map.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(lat,lng));


var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: pos,
    map: map,
    icon: 'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/green-dot.png',
    title: 'Hello World!'
});


var poly = new google.maps.Polyline({
    map: map,
    path: path,
    strokeColor: '#000000',
    strokeOpacity: 1.0,
    strokeWeight: 4
})

path.push(new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng));
poly.setPath(path);     

}

function onError(error) 
{
    alert('code: '    + error.code    + '\n' +
          'message: ' + error.message + '\n');
}
watchID = navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(onSuccess, onError, options);
}

google.maps.Event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize)
```

**Index.Html**

```
 <head>
  <script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
 </head>

<body onload="initialize()">
    <div id="map" style="width:375px;height:480px;"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: I get a javascript error with the posted code: `Cannot read property 'addDomListener' of undefined` (javascript is case sensitive "Event" != "event")

Comment: Seems to work as you expect on my cell phone, shows me in my house (on my desktop the position if off by a fair amount).  Maybe it is an issue with the position sensor in your phone.

Comment: Hi, there thank you for the quick reply. I haven't got that error when I run it on the emulator and check the console. Is there any way to check that it might be an issue with the sensors in my phone besides the obvious way of checking with another phone (don't have another spare at the moment)

Comment: After going for a walk and trying it again it appears to make several markers around the proximity that I'm in and then after about 4/5 seconds it works as expected and tracks the movement of my phone. Just seems to be the initial start up now.

Comment: I have found that some inside locations don't get a good GPS signal.  That might be what you are seeing.